Is it possible to know that a picklist field is sorted alphabetically?
For a picklist field it is possible to order the items alphabetically. For this to apply navigate to the picklist field in Object Manager and choose Reorder, like shown in the next image.

Than select Display values alphabetically, not in the order entered.

My question is, is it possible within apex to know if a field is sorted alphabetically?

That attribute isn't stored--it's a one-time operation. The only way to know if the list is currently sorted would be to describe the picklist and check each picklist entry.

Thanks @sfdcfox, the walking Saleforce library:). Ok this is indeed how we approached it. Thanks.

do you happen to know wheter the values are sorted based on value or by label?

@PieterJacob It's by label.
